# 404 Redirect on Apache - Do I need a header?

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, http, http-status-code-404

On Apache server, I added this to `.htaccess`:

```
ErrorDocument 404 /404.htm
```

Do I need to add any 404 specific code to the '`404.htm`' file? Like headers? Or does Apache take care of this automatically?

Thanks.

Comment: apache will take care of the right response code. no need to worry

Comment: if there is no 404.htm found apache will serve it's default 404 page (the awful text that looks like no-one cares about the site..) otherwise just add your normal code to the 404.html page and the text as what you were looking for was not found, etc. try to offer them some links they may want, if you have a search option show or highlight that etc